# how to use json to decode

Tags: android, json, flutter

I used Json in my app in the first is work and now the json.decode() is not working.
my function :

```
load() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    items k;
    my_fav.clear();
    String key = 'ss';
    myStringList = prefs.getStringList('favorite');
    print(myStringList.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < myStringList.length; i++) {
      prefs.setString(key, myStringList[i]);
      print(prefs.getString(key));

      k = items.fromJson(await json.decode(prefs.getString(key)));

      if (!Id.contains(k.title)) {
        my_fav.add(k);
        Id.add(k.title);
      }
    }}
```

this is the exception that I recivied ::::

```
E/flutter ( 6480): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)
E/flutter ( 6480): 
E/flutter ( 6480): ^
E/flutter ( 6480): 
E/flutter ( 6480): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1392:5)
E/flutter ( 6480): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.close (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:510:7)
E/flutter ( 6480): #2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:30:10)
E/flutter ( 6480): #3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:493:36)
E/flutter ( 6480): #4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:151:41)
E/flutter ( 6480): #5      _Beloved.load (package:kurdish_app/pages/beloved.dart:83:37)
E/flutter ( 6480): #6      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
```

Comment: can you add one of the strings which you are trying to decode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it couldn't decode your String properly. You should try to encode your string using [jsonEncode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html) to be sure that your JSON is correctly formatted and then use [jsonDecode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html).
You should also test the String you are using with JSON formatter. (I'm often using [this one](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/))